# mySQL Replace does not replace second token

Tags: mysql

I have the Following Query:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_NAME, 'KEYWORD', REPLACE(BUSINESS_NAME, ' ', '-')
FROM clearindia.business b
LEFT OUTER JOIN `clearindia`.`keywords_master` km ON km.KEYWORD_TEXT = b.BUSINESS_NAME
WHERE km.KEYWORD_TEXT IS NULL
AND b.business_name='Dey Radio Service'
GROUP BY BUSINESS_NAME
```

It gives me the following results:

```
  # BUSINESS_NAME, KEYWORD, REPLACE(BUSINESS_NAME, ' ', '-')
  'Dey Radio service', 'KEYWORD', 'Dey-Radio service'
```

REPLACE(BUSINESS_NAME, ' ', '-') is not working correctly and does not replace the second space with a '-'. Why is that?

Please Note: BUSINESS_NAME has a collation of utf_unicode_ci.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are needing to replace the data, at the time of querying the db? why not clean the data by the script (e.g. php or what ever language you are using)?

Comment: Is this will work? `SELECT REPLACE('Dey Radio service', ' ', '-')` try it.